# Accessing node.js modules within a webview tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js

I have a `nw` app which loads `index.html`

Within `index.html` I have a `<webview>` tag which loads `external.html`

In `index.html`, executing `var fs = require('fs')` succeeds, whereas executing the same in `external.html` fails.
So `node.js` modules are exposed to the main page only and not to `webview`.
On my `package.json` I have this:

```
  "webview": {
     "partitions": [
        {
          "name": "trusted",
          "accessible_resources": [ "<all_urls>" ]
        }
     ]
```

What can I do in order to make at least the `require` method available to `webview` content scripts? Is there a setting in `package.json`, or a particular attribute in `webview` to set? Or can I inject that method to the `webview` `window` object when `loadstop` event is fired? How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It will work, the nodeintegration attribute is add the node module in webview page also.
 example  ## webview name="", partitions="" nodeintegration webview/> ## here

Answer (score 0):

To enable Node.js support in WebView, add the allownw attribute to the webview tag. Then Node.js will be turned on, no matter it loads local file or remote site. Use this feature with caution because webview is normally supposed to load untrusted contents.
[enter link description here](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/webview%20Tag/)